# Scraping data from XML with python

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping

I want to get some data from [https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/api/search?limit=10000&text=&facets[0]name=type&facets[0]value=software&mediatype=xml](https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/api/search?limit=10000&text=&facets%5B0%5Dname=type&facets%5B0%5Dvalue=software&mediatype=xml)

What I need is the "title" and "GetCapabilitiesUrl" for every record. I have tried playing around with BeautifulSoup, but I can't find the right way to get the data I want.

Does someone know how to proceed with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. Thanks (Showing code you have written would be great)

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something but your URL seems to provide JSON, not XML.

Comment: BS4 is overkill for this. It looks like JSON already - could probably get away with `requests` and the standard library `json` module

Comment: Yeah. You are right. Got what I wanted by this:

`
import requests
import json

url = "https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/api/search?limit=10000&text=&facets[0]name=type&facets[0]value=software&mediatype=xml"

json_data = requests.get(url).json()

antall = json_data["NumFound"]

for i in range(antall):
    tittel = json_data["Results"][i]["Title"]

    print(tittel)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link you posted looks like a JSON file, not an XML file. You can see the difference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_xml.asp). You can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module in python to parse this data.

Once you get a string with the data from the website, you can use `json.loads()` to convert a string containing a JSON object into a python object.

The following code snippet will put all titles in a variable called `titles` and a urls in `urls`

```
import json
import urllib.request
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
raw_json_string = urllib.request.urlopen("https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/api/search?limit=10000&text=&facets%5B0%5Dname=type&facets%5B0%5Dvalue=software&mediatype=xml").read()
json_object = json.loads(raw_json_string)

titles = []
urls = []

for record in json_object["Results"]:
    titles.append(record["Title"])
    try:
        urls.append(record["GetCapabilitiesUrl"])
    except:
        pass
```

When writing the code, you can use an [online JSON viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to help you figure out the elements of dictionaries and lists.